# What can we use as a wireless switch for a ceiling light?

Tags: switch

I removed a light/ceiling fan that had a pull string when we installed my son's bunk bed (we didn't want the fan blades knocking him in the head).  We now want to install just a ceiling light.  There is electrical at the light location but no wall switch.  What wireless options for a ceiling light are there so my son can turn on the light when he walks into the room?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like [this](http://www.heath-zenith.com/prod_details.cgi?file=3.2.353&type=0&value=3.2), if there is room in the fixture:

[image: wireless socket]

The switch just mounts on the wall and uses a battery. There is no direct wiring to the fixture.  This company also makes a [hand held remote](http://www.heath-zenith.com/prod_details.cgi?file=3.0.461&type=0&value=3.0) that would work with the socket adapter (instead of or in addition to the switch) as well:

[image: remote]

There are also hard wired switching units that fit in a junction box, such as [this one](http://store.homeseer.com/store/Evolve-LFM-20-Z-Wave-Relay-Fixture-Module-P1007.aspx)

[image: remote hard wire unit]

This last one uses the Z-Wave remote system and needs compatible remote controls.

I would not suggest using a fan control box because there is much less venting/air space in a junction box than in a fan housing.